# Visual Studio 2012/C# breaks code execution, no breakpoint set

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I'm having a problem in Visual Studio 2012/C# which is driving me crazy. I have a particular line of code in a C# file with NO breakpoint set. Every time this line should be executed the debugger interrupts the execution of my code like a breakpoint was set. The only difference i noticed is the arrow on the left hand side, indicating the current step. Usually this arrow is yellow (when a breakpoint is set). In my case it is grey.

I have been searching for a solution but did not find anything useful to this. I tried deleting all breakpoints, build project, rebuild project, clean project and it still appears.

Does anyone have the same problems and found a solution this?

normal arrow: [image: normal arrow]

arrow in my case: [image: arrow in my case]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an uncaught exception? Can you show the code?

Comment: Is the method you're calling on that line tagged with `[DebuggerStepThrough]` ?

Comment: @kai I'm pretty shure it's not. When I get uncaught exceptions there appears a window (notification) with details to the exception which does not appear in my case...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen How can i check that?

Comment: Open your debugger/watch window, and enter `$exception` there. If the debugger stopped on some exception, you will be able to peek on it, read the message and stack trace. It;s strange that the "exception assistant" window didn't pop up.

Comment: enable all the exceptions with Ctrl+ Alt + E shortcut and check.

Comment: @Maverick they are already all checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code is currently executing, it calls something else, e.g. native code or .NET internal code and an exception happens there. You can see both arrows in the call stack window:

[image: Arrows in call stack window]

Perhaps you need to turn on "Show external code".

If you can't see the exception dialog, usually you can show it like this:

[image: Showing Exception in VS]

Comment: that's what i thought first, but the uncaught exception-window does not appear at all.

Comment: Do you have OzCode installed? OzCode replaces that window

Comment: No i don't have OzCode installed and the window appears when i have uncaught exceptions from other calls

Comment: ok, i found the problem. I had a Debugger.Break(); command in the function I was calling, and i am not able to set working breakpoints in this file (although it's my own code, idk why) as long as "Enable just my code" in the debug settings is checked. So, the code  was stopped, but not with an uncaught exception. Unchecking that option in the settings did the trick to find out what was going on, so i'll accept this as correct answer.