# Visual Studio Debugger's little blue arrow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

What is this little blue arrow about?

[image]

It freezes execution of my ASP.NET program when I do not want it to (note the **disabled** breakpoint).

Any resources or clarification around what this little guy represents would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012/C# breaks code execution, no breakpoint set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742602/visual-studio-2012-c-breaks-code-execution-no-breakpoint-set)

Comment: abichango has spotted the answer on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742602/visual-studio-2012-c-breaks-code-execution-no-breakpoint-set?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a Debugger.Break(); command on the function or code called on that line. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742602/visual-studio-2012-c-breaks-code-execution-no-breakpoint-set) for more info.

**EDIT**

Answer by @Thomas:

> This line of code is currently executing, it calls something else,
>   e.g. native code or .NET internal code and an exception happens there.
>   You can see both arrows in the call stack window:
>
> [image]
>
> Perhaps you need to turn on "Show external code".
>
> [image]
>
> If you can't see the exception dialog, usually you can show it like
>   this:
>
> Showing Exception in VS

Comment: the link says something different than your first sentence, you should include the information from the link